# Ionic 2 - menuClose On Image Click

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2

In Ionic 2 you can add the

> menuClose

directive on a button so that the side menu will close upon being clicked.

I would like to close the menu when an image is clicked, rather than a button. The image is located within the ion-menu.

Is there a way I can call the menu close function when the image is clicked?

Here's my HTML

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <img src="myLogo.svg" class='logo' (click)='closeSideMenu()'>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the MenuController directly in your component

```
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {}

  closeSideMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.close();
  }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/)

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test but will let you know when I do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a workaround, make a button with a background image, without label using css: background: url('background.jpg');

Comment: I need to add the menuClose to the image, as the idea is I want the menu to close when the user clicks the image. The buttons are working as intended. Since the menuClose directive is just for buttons, I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, reading your question in a fast way, I will try to find a solution and go back